# Displaying different hidden textboxes from Dataset on Page Header in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, textbox, header, ssrs-tablix

In my report I have Matrices that appear according to the parameters on a SP. Each Matrix holds an specific "code"/description which I want to show on the Page Header accordingly.

I tried using an `<<Expr>>` but that didn't work well as it only shows the first record of the database instead of the code for the specific matrix.

Then I found out that I can show an specific textbox with "`=ReportItems!TextBoxXX.Value`" and so I added to each Matrix the code value hidden.

Now I thought of adding in the page header inside a TextBox a concatenation of all the values, but that didn't work, and I got a:

```
"The value expression for the textrun "textboc11.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]" refers to more than one report item. An expression in a page header or footer can refer to only one report item.
```

Hence, my next attempt consisted of adding separate text boxes each one with the desired TextBox Value and one behind the other (like a Pile of textboxes). Everything working now, except that the "space" that each textbox occupies appears in the report showing the desired value and a white space above each textbox when rendered.

Any ideas of how to prevent this behavior? Maybe creating an array with the textboxes and creating an IIF or I don't know, I've been searching for days and nothing seems like a good approach.

I hope someone can give me some advice and that I explained myself.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the codes in the parameters you are passing to the SP? Are they in the Data?
If your matrix changes on each page, and the code is in the matrix, you would only need to refer to that ReportItem once in the header and it would change on each page to match the matrix. 
We need to see what your data looks like.